# Unable to access Evernote data: Thrift.Transport.TTransportException

Tags: c#, evernote

I`m trying to access my notebooks on Evernote by C#.NET (using Evernote Cloud SDK 2.0 for Windows) and using a DEVELOPER TOKEN. The following sample raises and exception:

```
ENSession.SetSharedSessionDeveloperToken("my token", "https://www.evernote.com"); 

if (ENSession.SharedSession.IsAuthenticated == false)
{
    ENSession.SharedSession.AuthenticateToEvernote();
}

// Get a list of all notebooks in the user's account.
List<ENNotebook> myNotebookList = ENSession.SharedSession.ListNotebooks();
```

The exception occurs in the last line:

```
List<ENNotebook> myNotebookList = ENSession.SharedSession.ListNotebooks();
```

**Exception: Thrift.Transport.TTransportException: 'Cannot read, Remote side has closed'**

p.s: I'm using production instead sandbox

How to handle with this exception ?

Answer (score 0):

The second argument of `ENSession.SetSharedSessionDeveloperToken` is NoteStore URL, which you can get on this page https://www.evernote.com/api/DeveloperToken.action.